# Multi level dropdown accessibility improvements

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, w3c, wai-aria

I am trying to create a multi level drodown menu with the following code:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="company.html">Company</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">More Stuff</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="team.html">Team</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="goals.html">Goals</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="company.html">Chairs</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="team.html">Beds</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="goals.html">Fireplace</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="photos.html">Onother</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With some jQuery I have hidden all the second/third level items and added a class that will show a "+" in the right side via CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJug9/1/

This works fine for most users, but when I try to use this with VoiceOver on Mac I just can't simply find a way to navigate. Maybe because I don't know all the things about VoiceOver or I am doing something wrong with HTML and JS

Is there something missing from my code that could improve accessibility for blind people using screen readers. What should I do more and why for this particular example.

Any up to date tools or documentation that will put me up to speed about accessibility. I think that the W3C accessibility website is too cluttered and confusing. I read some things about Aria too, but the documentation is really complicated and some people say that using proper markup is good enough.

Please try to answer for this example

**UPDATE**
I added visibility hidden to the hidden ul's as the screen reader does not speak invisible elements and I will still be able to use CSS3 for the height transition
Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJug9/3/

Comment: make a focus event for all expanders that does whatever the click does except that it first hides all open expanders. also, use display:none to get the hidden elements out of the tab sequence.

Comment: @dandavis - I noticed that using only the height to hide elements will not hide from the screen reader. Thanks!

Comment: are you still having an issue with your updated demo? (works for me)

Comment: @dandavis - no, works fine for me, but I want to get some answers from the guys who are using this type of navigation. I also think that you can do something with aria like 'Instead of link 'About +' to say 'Expand About us navigation items"

Comment: use a title to describe functionality. aria-described-by and aria-labelled-by are overkill for such a simple widget.

Comment: @dandavis - cool, thank you. After doing some reading I was scared that I have to do a lot more work. All the aria documentation scares me a lot. What I did is started learning about the Mac Voice Over and looks like that app is really smart and easy to use one you learn all the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47064/discussion-between-adrian-florescu-and-dandavis)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advancing VoiceOver to a specified element in mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250847/advancing-voiceover-to-a-specified-element-in-mobile-safari)